# hello i need a proper example to develop NLP using spacy Python

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I searched a lot regarding the spacy library for the NLP and i learned a lot of thing about spacy and NLP.

But, nowadays I want to implement spacy but I didn't find a proper example to do that. Can anyone guide me through the process or provide me any example link for spacy.

i referred to this: https://spacy.io/usage/

Or give me any other library with runnable example to develop NLP.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not clear what you mean with "develop NLP". What do you need to do in particular? What's your end goal?

Comment: Hello !!!! Welcome to StackOverflow!!!! The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to try to solve your own problem first, as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. For more information, please see
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i want develop my own chatbot which can i integrate with any application and train that as per needed @AKX

Answer (score 3):

Although your question is highly unclear, from what I understand, you want to build the NPL pipeline with SpaCY. I can guide you through the basic steps but this is a vast area and you'll pretty much have to figure stuff out on your own. But, it'll be easier after this.

So, you have to take a look at the SpaCY API [documentation](https://spacy.io/api/).

Basic steps in any NLP pipeline are the following:

1. Language detection (self explanatory, if you're working with some dataset, you know what the language is and you can adapt your pipeline to that). When you know a language you have to download a correct models from SpaCY. The instructions are [here](https://spacy.io/models/). Let's use English for this example. In your command line just type `python -m spacy download en` and then import it to the preprocessing script like this:

   ```
   import spacy
   nlp = spacy.load('en')
   ```
2. Tokenization - this is the process of splitting the text into words. It's not enough to just do `text.split()` (ex. `there's` would be treated as a single word but it's actually two words `there` and `is`). So here we use Tokenizers. In SpaCy you can do something like:

   ```
   nlp_doc = nlp(text)
   ```

where `text` is your dataset corpus or a sample from a dataset. You can read more about the document instance [here](https://spacy.io/api/doc)

3. Punctuation removal - pretty self explanatory process, done by the method in the previous step. To remove punctuation, just type:

   ```
   import re

   # removing punctuation tokens
   text_no_punct = [token.text for token in doc if not token.is_punct]

   # remove punctuation tokens that are in the word string like 'bye!' -> 'bye'
   REPLACE_PUNCT = re.compile("(\.)|(\;)|(\:)|(\!)|(\')|(\?)|(\,)|(\")|(\()|(\))|(\[)|(\])")
   text_no_punct = [REPLACE_PUNCT.sub("", tok.text) for tok in text_no_punct]
   ```
4. POS tagging - short for Part-Of-Speech tagging. It is the process of marking up a word in a text as corresponding to a particular part of speech. For example:

   ```
   A/DT Part-Of-Speech/NNP Tagger/NNP is/VBZ a/DT piece/NN of/IN
   software/NN that/WDT reads/VBZ text/NN in/IN some/DT
   language/NN and/CC assigns/VBZ parts/NNS of/IN speech/NN to/TO
   each/DT word/NN ,/, such/JJ as/IN noun/NN ,/, verb/NN ,/,
   adjective/NN ,/, etc./FW./.
   ```

where the uppercase codes after the slash are a standard word tags. A list of tags can be found [here](https://www.ling.upenn.edu/courses/Fall_2003/ling001/penn_treebank_pos.html)

In SpaCy, this is already done by putting the text into `nlp` instance. You can get the tags with:

```
    for token in doc:
        print(token.text, token.tag_)
```

5. Morphological processing: lemmatization - it's a process of transforming the words into a linguistically valid base form, called the lemma:

   ```
   nouns → singular nominative form
   verbs → infinitive form
   adjectives → singular, nominative, masculine, indefinitive, positive form
   ```

In SpaCy, it's also already done for you by putting the text into `nlp` instance. You can get the lemma of every word by:

```
    for token in doc:
        print(token.text, token.lemma_)
```

6. Removing stopwords - stopwords are the words that are not bringing any new information or meaning to the sentence and can be omitted. You guessed, it's also already done for you by `nlp` instance. To filter the stopwords just type:

   ```
   text_without_stopwords = [token.text for token in doc if not token.is_stop]
   doc = nlp(' '.join(text_without_stopwords))
   ```

Now you have a clean dataset. You can now use [word2vec](https://code.google.com/archive/p/word2vec/) or [GloVe](https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/) pretrained models to create a word vectors and input your data to some model. But let's leave that for another post. I hope this is clear enough :)